# Как выполнить поиск в elasticsearch по окончанию?

Tags: elasticsearch

Реализована запись логов в elasticsearch, реализован поиск по нескольким полям.

```
curl -X GET 1.2.3.4:9200/logs/_search?pretty=true -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"size":30,"query":{"constant_score":{"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"ident.keyword":["sip"]}}]}}}},"post_filter":{"multi_match":{"query":"9998887722","fields":["message","loglevel","env","site","project","ident"]}},"sort":[{"@timestamp":"desc"}]}'
```

В основном, поиск производится в логах по номеру телефона. Номер телефона может начинаться с 7, +7, 8 или вообще без префикса.
Сейчас поиск работает по точному соответствию, потому нужно точно знать, в каком формате номер записан в лог. Хотелось бы ввести номер без префикса и найти все его варианты, например `+79998887722, 89998887722, 9998887722, 79998887722, A019998887722`

Возможно ли как-то изменить запрос, что бы искать данные по суффиксу?

Обратный аналог prefix_len не нашел в документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [regexp query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)
В вашем случае придется обернуть multi_match в bool query примерно так:

```
{
"bool": {
    "should": [
        {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": "9998887722",
                "fields": ["message","loglevel","env","site","project"]
            }
        },
        {
            "regexp": {
                "ident": {
                    "value": ".*9998887722"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Если я правильно понял, что телефон хранится в поле **ident**. Регулярное выражение можно тоже изменить.